# Cookies are not being sent in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, axios

I'm using Next JS as a client.

Using the js-cookie library I am setting a cookie called FarmId: Cookies.set('FarmId', farmId)

In my axios.create I am already setting the withCredentials property to true:

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
})
```

However, my problem is that when I make the request to the API, the Cookie is not being sent

```
const response = await api.get<IFarm[]>('/api/Farms')
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekra6.png)

Through Postman, it is sending normally, I also tested it by creating a NodeJS application and it worked normally too.

I'm trying to figure out how to send the cookies to the API and hope to find a solution that will help me resolve this issue